# Removing duplicate characters in string preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

`$value =  "ABCC@CmCCCCm@CCmC@CDEF";`

`$clear = preg_replace('/@{1,}/', "", $value);`

I need to remove duplicate @ and get something like:

`ABCC@CmCCCCmCCmCCDEF` (I need only first @)

**How to do that?**

Comment: First of all, tell us what you have tried

Comment: `strpos` + `substr_replace`, no need to use regular expressions (especially if you cannot write one - it will be painful for you to maintain this code)

Comment: @zerkms: it can be a good way, you must only skip the first one.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte: it can be, but as I said - it's always a good idea to always write a code you're able to maintain. Otherwise OP will be a frequent visitor here for every trivial change. And, no, I don't think it's a good way to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regex way:

```
$clear = preg_replace('~(?>@|\G(?<!^)[^@]*)\K@*~', '', $value);
```

details:

```
(?:           # open a non capturing group
    @         # literal @
  |           # OR
    \G(?<!^)  # contiguous to a precedent match, not at the start of the string
    [^@]*     # all characters except @, zero or more times
)\K           # close the group and reset the match from the result
@*            # zero or more literal @
```

Comment: Isn't that an atomic group ? Anyways +1000 :)

Comment: @HamZa: yes it is, and it can by replaced by `(?:...)` since it is  useless with an alternation inside.

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
// The original string
$str = 'ABCC@CmCCCCm@CCmC@CDEF';
// Position of the first @ sign
$pos = strpos($str, '@');
// Left side of the first found @ sign
$str_sub_1 = substr($str, 0, $pos + 1);
// Right side of the first found @ sign
$str_sub_2 = substr($str, $pos);
// Replace all @ signs in the right side
$str_sub_2_repl = str_replace('@', '', $str_sub_2);
// Join the left and right sides again
$str_new = $str_sub_1 . $str_sub_2_repl;
echo $str_new;
```